# Menu I wonder how to style and IE7 to accept this

Tags: css

I'd try to be as short as possible as no one likes to read long stuff and waste time,
now it is a menu with a twisted center image that should look like this - http://bit.ly/dXUZcX
but I wonder how to make it's left and right repetitive parts to repeat one only left and the other only right. I tried some stuff but didn't work out so decided to ask here if someone has idea how it gonna happen.
And these divs are transparent as there is a repetitive bg behind them.
Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: So you just want us to handle the part where the "left and right parts repeats as wide as is needed"? Could you show the code you currently have?

Comment: Will you need special background behind that menu?

Comment: when both divs (left/right) are transparent - what do you need them for anyway? why not just center the one in the middle?

Answer (score 0):

You can't to it like that with pure css since there is currently no way to calculate widths. You could do it with Javascript (maybe you try using jQuery) or you can simply use images, if that's an option.

Here's my image based solution:

http://www.fabsn.de/trash/stackoverflow/orchid/index.htm

Comment: fabsn Thank you! and for the time you took to make the example. And thanks everyone for the input! Now I have plenty of ideas to play around with to suit the overall style.